# select values around null and append value to another column BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to check for the values around null; if the values around null are the same, nothing should be done. If the values around null are not the same, i would like to copy nulls to another column in the same position as in the original column.

Example:

```
Item    DesiredColumn

a        
null     null     
null     null
b        
null     
null     
b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  IF(
    LAST_VALUE(Item IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) != 
    FIRST_VALUE(Item IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    AND Item IS NULL, NULL, ''
  ) AS DesiredColumn
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If applied to sample data from your question (as in below example)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 ts, 'a' Item UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'b' 
)
SELECT *, 
  IF(
    LAST_VALUE(Item IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) != 
    FIRST_VALUE(Item IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY ts ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
    AND Item IS NULL, NULL, ''
  ) AS DesiredColumn
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

output is

```
Row ts  Item    DesiredColumn    
1   1   a        
2   2   null    null     
3   3   null    null     
4   4   b        
5   5   null         
6   6   null         
7   7   b
```

Note: you must have column in your table that identifies order in which comparison is to happen. In my example above such column is `ts`